# How to keep identical vertical spacing in a custom list environment regardless of descenders / ascenders?

Tags: tables, lists, typography

I am currently defining a custom list environment for a CV. The environment works as desired, but it has one caveat. Namely, letters with ascenders and descenders affect the row width, thus making the output ugly. There goes a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt % for ragged2e document settting
  #1\hspace*{0pt plus -1fil}\mbox{}&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

\begin{document}

  \begin{entrylist}

   \entry
    {Office addr}
    {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
    {}
    {}

   \entry
    {Web addr}
    {www.somename.com}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Pers email}
    {somename a aaa}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Work email}
    {veryfancyname2 a aaa}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {UK phone}
    {+00 0000 000000}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {SP phone}
    {+00 000 000 000}
    {}
    {}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I claim that the output is ugly because the empty space between rows 1 & 2 is greater than the empty space between lines 2 & 3, for example. It might be a bit tricky to see, but the different spacing I mention is there, and I am sure that the culprit of this is the use of letters with descenders.

I would like to find a way **to make sure that the list environment defined above keeps the same amount of space between lines, regardless of letters with ascenders / descenders.**

Thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Comment: Add a `\strut` as the first entry in the `\parbox`.  Depending on whether these can become multi-line entries, you may also need to enter a `\strut` at the end of the `\parbox`, too.  This might be problematic, as the value of `#4` determines if you leave vertical mode or not after the `\par` (whereas the `\strut` will definitely force an exit from vertical mode).

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comment. However, I have one question: when you write ‘multi-line entries’, what do you exactly mean? As you can see in the MWE, each `\entry` has four `{}`, although some of them are empty. There might bu up to four `{}` in each entry, but each `{}` will contain information that will span at most one single line (i.e., no `{}` is multi-lined). Will I have issues if I apply your suggestion?

Comment: I am referring to whether the content is long enough so that the `\parbox` wraps into multiple lines or not.

Comment: Then I won’t have a problem. Thank you very much for your answer —I tested it and works like a charm. Feel free to post it as answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment I suggested adding a `\strut` at the beginning of the `\parbox`, so that the "top" of the parbox would occupy the full vertical extent of a text-line.  Normally, I might also advocate a `\strut` at the end of the `\parbox` (for cases where line wrapping occurs).  However, in this case, because the parbox has, near the end, `{...\par}#4\vspace{\parsep}`, a `\strut` would take one out of vertical mode even when `#4` was blank, which would not be the likely intent of the OP.  The OP assured me that this approach, with the single `\strut` at the outset, works to his satisfaction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt % for ragged2e document settting
  #1\hspace*{0pt plus -1fil}\mbox{}&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

\begin{document}

  \begin{entrylist}

   \entry
    {Office addr}
    {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
    {}
    {}

   \entry
    {Web addr}
    {www.somename.com}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Pers email}
    {somename a aaa}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Work email}
    {veryfancyname2 a aaa}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {UK phone}
    {+00 0000 000000}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {SP phone}
    {+00 000 000 000}
    {}
    {}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the `\parbox` is for. You can exploit `tabularx` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \tabularx{\textwidth}[t]{@{}l@{\quad}X@{}}
}{%
  \endtabularx
}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&#2\hfill
  \mbox{\footnotesize #3}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax\else\\#4\fi
  \\\noalign{\vspace{\parsep}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

% this is just to show the baselines
\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\hbox{\vrule\vtop{
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
  \hbox{\strut\vrule height0.1pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}\vskip\parsep
}}}%
  \begin{entrylist}

   \entry
    {Office addr}
    {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
    {}
    {}

   \entry
    {Web addr}
    {www.somename.com}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Pers email}
    {somename a aaa}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Work email}
    {veryfancyname2 a aaa}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {UK phone}
    {+00 0000 000000}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {SP phone}
    {+00 000 000 000}
    {}
    {}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]